# No Objects Library button in Xcode 10, just Snippets Library

Tags: xcode, xcode10

Objects Library button is unavailable:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objects Library button is visible only when edited file is xib or stroyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case of SwiftUI and xcode 11:

UI elements are shown in Library only when Canvas is shown (option + cmd + enter).